# How do you get the Unicode code of a character in a SQL Server database table?

Tags: sql-server, database, unicode, character

I've been given a string of characters in a SQL Server DB table, in a column of datatype `nvarchar(510)`. I'm trying to get the Unicode code of the first character in the string using this SQL:

```
select unicode(substring(asciicharacter, 1, 1)) 
from TableAscii;
```

but no matter what the character is, the select returns "1". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This code seems to be working fine for me when I test. I actually haven't been able to make it fail. I think there is something going on outside of this SQL

Comment: You should not need the `substring` call, since the `unicode` function returns the Unicode value of the *first* character of its argument.

Comment: It is a little concerning that your column name is "asciicharacter" in a table named "TableAscii" yet you say it is defined as nvarchar(510). In addition, you don't select a specific row - so do you have multiple rows?

Comment: Thanks for the comments: 1) yes, the table and column names are misnomers, but the column is indeed nvarchar(510) and 2) there is only one row in the table.